# Cloud Run fails with SSL errors or uncaught signal errors when queueing tasks to cloud task

Tags: python, google-cloud-platform, cloud, google-cloud-run, google-cloud-tasks

#### Service Description

I am trying a service architecture to be implemented in one of my services but Cloud Run is failing with strange errors for me.

I have a web portal based on backstage that supports business users in automating some actions. for example assume we need to create 6000 students in a system, the user will fill some fields in a form, attach a csv file including all the information and will submit.

on clicking submit the request is issued to a Cloud Run service, Cloud run validates the csv and ensures the data is ok, divides the file data into chunks (to stay within cloud tasks task size limit) and queues each chunk to a cloud task which acts as a queuer.

the queuer cloud task which receives a chunk of the file, will queue one task per object (student to be created in our case).

so in numbers, assume we have 6000 students to be created, the 6000 is divided into chunks of 100 chunks, each chunk has 60 students, and each chunk will forwarded to a cloud task (60 tasks)

each task with a chunk will break this chunk into a set of tasks. so each task from the 60 cloud tasks will create 100 cloud tasks.

I am sharing below a simple code that mimics this scenario. I am using python 3.10, goblet-gcp package for deployment.

```
from goblet import Goblet, goblet_entrypoint

app = Goblet(
    function_name="test-google-support",
    backend="cloudrun",
    routes_type="cloudrun",
)
goblet_entrypoint(app)

cloud_task_queue = app.cloudtaskqueue(
    "test-service",
    config={
        "rateLimits": {
            "maxDispatchesPerSecond": 10,
            "maxBurstSize": 10,
            "maxConcurrentDispatches": 1,
        },
        "retryConfig": {
            "maxAttempts": 1,
            "minBackoff": "0.100s",
            "maxBackoff": "3600s",
            "maxDoublings": 16,
        },
    },
)


@app.route("/test-gcp-support", methods=["POST"])
def submit_bulk_campaigns_management():
    """Validation method for bulk campaigns creation/update. Dev portal calls are routed here"""
    json_data = app.current_request.json
    i = 0
    for chunk in json_data["chunks"]:
        i += 1
        app.log.info(f"queueing chunk {i}")
        cloud_task_queue.enqueue(
            target="test-queuer",
            payload={
                "chunk": chunk,
                "batch_id": i
            },
        )
        app.log.info(f"queued chunk {i}")
    app.log.info(f"queued {i} chunks ...")
    return "Successfully submitted request.", 200, {}


@app.cloudtasktarget(name="test-queuer")
def queue_campaign_creation_tasks(request):
    json_data = request.json
    chunk = json_data.get("chunk")
    batch_id = json_data.get("batch_id")

    i = 0
    for object in chunk:
        i += 1
        app.log.info(f"queuing task {i} of batch {batch_id}")
        cloud_task_queue.enqueue(
            target="single-object-management",
            payload={
                "data": object,
                "batch_id": batch_id,
                "task_id": i,
            },
        )
        app.log.info(f"queued task {i} of batch {batch_id}")
    app.log.info(f"queued {i} tasks for chunk {batch_id}")
    return "queued all tasks", 200, {}


@app.cloudtasktarget(name="single-object-management")
def single_campaign_management(request):
    json_data = request.json
    app.log.info(f"received json_data: {json_data}")
    return "Success", 200, {}
```

Docker file (automated through goblet-gcp) is

```
# https://hub.docker.com/_/python
FROM python:3.10-slim

# setup environment
ENV APP_HOME /app
WORKDIR $APP_HOME

# install keyring backend to handle artifact registry authentication
# RUN pip install keyrings.google-artifactregistry-auth==1.1.1

# Install dependencies.
COPY requirements.txt .
RUN pip install -r requirements.txt

# Copy local code to the container image.
COPY . .
```

requirements.txt

```
goblet-gcp==0.10.5
pydantic==1.10.11
```

and the request body is

```
{
    "chunks":[
        [
            {
                "task":"1.1"
            },
            {
                "task":"1.2"
            }

        ],
        [
            {
                "task":"2.1"
            },
            {
                "task":"2.2"
            }

        ],
        [
            {
                "task":"2.1"
            },
            {
                "task":"2.2"
            }

        ],
        [
            {
                "task":"2.1"
            },
            {
                "task":"2.2"
            }

        ]
    ]
}
```

I am using the following cloud run config: concurrency is set to 80, timeout 300, no startup boost, cpu is not allways allocated, RAM is 512MB and CPU is set to  1, there is serverless VPC connector.

### Issue

We have different scenarios

1- **Scenario 1** : on queuing the second chunk from the main route to the queuer task we receive SSL errors as below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2213, in __call__
    return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2193, in wsgi_app
    response = self.handle_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 2190, in wsgi_app
    response = self.full_dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1486, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1484, in full_dispatch_request
    rv = self.dispatch_request()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/flask/app.py", line 1469, in dispatch_request
    return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/functions_framework/__init__.py", line 130, in view_func
    return function(request._get_current_object())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/goblet/app.py", line 160, in goblet_entrypoint_wrapper
    return app(request, context)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/goblet/decorators.py", line 427, in __call__
    response = self.handlers["route"](request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/goblet/handlers/routes.py", line 93, in __call__
    return entry(request)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/goblet/handlers/routes.py", line 413, in __call__
    resp = self.route_function(**args)
  File "/app/main.py", line 36, in submit_bulk_campaigns_management
    cloud_task_queue.enqueue(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/goblet/infrastructures/cloudtask.py", line 72, in enqueue
    task = self.build_task(target, payload, in_seconds, task_name, deadline)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/goblet/infrastructures/cloudtask.py", line 28, in build_task
    "url": self.backend.http_endpoint,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/goblet/backends/cloudrun.py", line 221, in http_endpoint
    return get_cloudrun_url(self.client, self.name)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/goblet/common_cloud_actions.py", line 216, in get_cloudrun_url
    resp = client.execute(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/goblet_gcp_client/client.py", line 195, in execute
    return getattr(api_chain, api)(**_params).execute()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/_helpers.py", line 130, in positional_wrapper
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 923, in execute
    resp, content = _retry_request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 222, in _retry_request
    raise exception
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/googleapiclient/http.py", line 191, in _retry_request
    resp, content = http.request(uri, method, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/google_auth_httplib2.py", line 218, in request
    response, content = self.http.request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1724, in request
    (response, content) = self._request(
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1444, in _request
    (response, content) = self._conn_request(conn, request_uri, method, body, headers)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/site-packages/httplib2/__init__.py", line 1396, in _conn_request
    response = conn.getresponse()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1375, in getresponse
    response.begin()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 318, in begin
    version, status, reason = self._read_status()
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 279, in _read_status
    line = str(self.fp.readline(_MAXLINE + 1), "iso-8859-1")
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/socket.py", line 705, in readinto
    return self._sock.recv_into(b)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1307, in recv_into
    return self.read(nbytes, buffer)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/ssl.py", line 1163, in read
    return self._sslobj.read(len, buffer)
ssl.SSLError: [SSL: WRONG_VERSION_NUMBER] wrong version number (_ssl.c:2578)"
```

2- **Scenario 2**: on queueing the second chunk from the main route to the queuer task , the service shut down with an uncaught signal error (signal 11) as below

```
severity: "ERROR"
textPayload: "Uncaught signal: 11, pid=2, tid=61, fault_addr=0."
```

3- **Scenario 3**: sometimes the services completes the request successfully.

### Actions to resolve

for the simple service shared above, I increased the min instances to 2, and it's working fine. I still don't know how the errors above correlates with instances number, which blocks the proper sizing activity of the service.

Any thoughts on the errors above?